# XMLHttpRequest keeps coming back null

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

So my code is calling for a file on my server "zom3.ms3d" which I have confirmed is there, and you can too, along with all the source code for this. (http://www.pso2u.com)

This is the code in question:

```
function getMs3dModel(model, name){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', name, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            parseBinFile(model, name, this.response);
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
```

And this is where it prints the contents (or first 10 bytes of it)

```
function parseBinFile(model, name, buffer){

        var headerStr = new DataView(buffer, 0, 10);  
        console.log(headerStr);
    }
```

Why is my request coming back null?

Comment: What browser are you using? Running Safari on Mac the response is an array buffer with a length of 99113 bytes. This sounds like what you were actually expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `xhr.response`, rather than `this.reponse`, as suggested by [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using?  xhr.onload is part of XMLHttpRequest Level 2.  Here is the list of browsers supporting it:  http://caniuse.com/xhr2

Your code looks good, though I would use  *xhr.response*, not *this.response*   (I generally avoid 'this' these days).

Comment: Aurora (Firefox) 15.0a2 (2012-06-28)